# Validation Error format in spring boot with Message Resource

Tags: spring-boot, validation

i'm trying to get a well-formatted validation error message from message resource.

Expected: username can't be empty
What I get: can't be empty.
validation_en.properties :

```
NotEmpty=can't be empty
```

messages_en.properties

```
username=Username
```

My Class

```
    @Value
public class LoginForm{
    @NotEmpty
    private final String username;
...
```

Configuration Class:

```
    @Configuration
public class WebAdaptorConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource resource =
                new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resource.setBasenames("messages","validation");
        resource.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return resource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("fa"));
        return sessionLocaleResolver;
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return bean;
    }

}
```

View:

```
<label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}"
                        class="validation-message"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've specified the default message for the `@NotEmpty` constraint to always be 'can't be empty'.

In order to use your custom message for the `@NotEmpty` constraint specifically validating the `username` field in your `LoginForm`, you need to follow the message property naming convention:

Constraint.formName.propertyName

So in your case, the message property for your `username` property becomes `NotEmpty.loginForm.username=username can't be empty`

I couldn't find any reference to that convention in the Hibernate validator docs or Spring docs but this article also explains it - https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-with-bean-validation-api

Comment: I want to avoid this kind of redundancy,if i have n fields and m error types with my way i should write n+m lines but as you say it becomes n*m

Comment: You're right, it certainly would become repetitive. Unfortunately, to my knowledge at least, it has to be like that in order narrow it down to a specific form, which was your original question. Now, you do have the option of making it so all `@NotEmpty` validated `username` fields can have the same validation message: `NotEmpty.username=username can't be empty`